# Why cdist from scipy.spatial.distance is so fast?

Tags: python, euclidean-distance, scipy-spatial

I wanted to create a distance proximity matrix for **10060** records/ points, where each record/point has **23** attributes using euclidean distance as metric. I wrote code using nested for loops to calculate distance between each point(leading to *(n(n-1))/2)* computations). It took a long time(about 8 minutes). When I used cdist it took so much lesser time(**just 3 seconds !!!**). When I looked at the source code, the cdist also uses nested for loops and moreover it makes *n^2* computations(which is greater than the number of comparisons my logic does). ***What is making cdist execute faster and give correct output as well ?*** Please help me understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where did you read the source code? The [python code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2285) calls (if you follow it all the way down in the default `metric='euclidean'` case) the c code

```
static NPY_INLINE int
cdist_seuclidean(const double *XA, const double *XB, const double *var,
                 double *dm, const npy_intp num_rowsA, const npy_intp num_rowsB,
                 const npy_intp num_cols)
{
    npy_intp i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < num_rowsA; ++i) {
        const double *u = XA + (num_cols * i);
        for (j = 0; j < num_rowsB; ++j, ++dm) {
            const double *v = XB + (num_cols * j);
            *dm = seuclidean_distance(var, u, v, num_cols);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where `seuclidean_distance` is

```
static NPY_INLINE double
seuclidean_distance(const double *var, const double *u, const double *v,
                    const npy_intp n)
{
    double s = 0.0;
    npy_intp i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        const double d = u[i] - v[i];
        s += (d * d) / var[i];
    }
    return sqrt(s);
}
```

So it's actually a triple loop, but this is highly optimised C code. Python `for` loops are slow, they take up a lot of overhead and should never be used with numpy arrays because scipy/numpy can take advantage of the underlying memory data held within an `ndarray` object in ways that python can't.

Comment: I found the code at this location "https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2285-L2673". And yes I also understand that its a triple loop(was just neglecting the fact that any how I would need a third loop inside to calculate the distance). But I am not able to understand, that the number of computations I am doing is same in the code(moreover my code does less computations), but still it works much faster than my code, why is it so ?

Comment: Because it is in C. Using python loops on numpy objects is very slow and if you ever find yourself doing it, you are doing it wrong. I can't help you more unless you paste your code into your question. You've pasted the python code but that loop is not actually what is being run unless you pass a function, the actual algorithm is in the lines `cdist_fn = getattr(_distance_wrap,
                               "cdist_%s_%s_wrap" % (metric_name, typ));` `cdist_fn(XA, XB, dm, **kwargs)` which calls c code.

Comment: Okay. I think this might be the only case, that it is written in C, that is why it is so fast. I found source code in python so got confused. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SushodhanVaishampayan https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html has some examples of translating Python code to C (via Cython) and the resulting speedups…

Comment: This is not an answer. I have revised the code and when calling with a custom function there is no C code involved and it is still blazingly fast (at least for **pdist**). The question is still unanswered.